# IE6 can not load page

Tags: html, css, load, internet-explorer-6

Strange thing... 
I'm optimizing this page for explorer.
It works pretty fine in all browsers, but IE6 can not load some pages at all. Just an error "page can not be loaded". I've disabled the less css for IE6, but it did not help.

Can plz someone take a look at it?
Thx

Comment: hm, it seems that the problem is caused by google plus button api

Answer (score 0):

try the following:
Tools/Internet Options/ Delete temporary Files
It might help.

Answer (score -1):

IE6 is obsolete and unsupported by Microsoft, also it is well known to be a horrible browser.  Why are you bothering with it?

http://www.ie6countdown.com/

Comment: because my client wants it ;)

Comment: if you are trying to help you're client out you should explain that it's a poor choice and explain the benefits of moving off of an obsolete browser.  there is good information on wikipedia about why it's shit, particularly 'security concerns' and 'criticism' - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_6

Comment: ok, my client has modern browser and understands it. But you may know, that there are still a lot of people, who got ie6 at a workplace, and they can not upgrade.

Comment: they can upgrade once the right people understand its worthwhile (i.e. decision makers).  regardless, if modern browsers are available then there's no real reason to be building new applications for demonstrably inferior and out of date ones.